# Accessing variable from multiple objects with the same prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script "ScoreAdd" attached to a prefab "Obstacle" and in that script I change variable "score".
In my scene obstacles will be spawning and then in a short time deleted. I need to access that "score" from a **different** script on **different game object**. I dont know how to reference all Obstacle's scripts so i can then just take the variable "score" and then set the text by another script in scene to "score".
I was thinking of using events or tags or something but i dont konw how to reference all the Obstacles in scene.

Answer (score 0):

Think you can achieve your objective by using a Static variable. You can set the value to this variable and access it from anywhere you want in the program. Don't have to instantiate an object for this. The value will remain the same all across.

Comment: Oh thanks. I'm kinda new to unity and didnt't knew what the classes do. Now I know ;D